# Angular 2 Check if email is valid

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to build a simple validation form using the following template driven form for anguar 2. However, I am getting the following error.

> error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Error in ./LoginComponent class LoginComponent - inline template:4:32 caused by: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

I believe the error is comming from !email.vaid. However I do not understand why.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !email.valid }">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !email.valid" class="help-block">Email is required</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything seems okay ! not sure but could you please replace `*ngIf` by `[hidden]` and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"     [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" required />
```

You are accessing email property on model object .Does model object exist in your class?
Try this code

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !email.valid }">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" #email="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="!email.valid" class="help-block">Email is required</div>
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>
       `,
     })
    export class App {
    name:string;
    user:any = {
      email:'test'
    }
```

Comment: I dont have name or user email in my actual component because I was under the impression that template driven form is self contained int he template so any reference to the component is not necessary. However, I do have  model: any = {}; just so that I can access the form results.

I think everything fails at f.submitted && !email.valid. Is it because this "email" can not be accessed because the "email" is declared at a lower level where the input is?

Comment: now the problem lies in the fact that you are defining model object in your component as any.You have to define an interface which will be of your custom type and then assign thaat type to model so that email property exists on model object.otherwise it will always be undefined.try this plunkr [link]https://plnkr.co/edit/W6cxKp8azRT8Lg1L8uVj?p=preview @user172902

Answer (score 1):

As Karan Garg suggested, it looks like email is undefined. Angular 2's templates give you a nice syntax for checking if values are defined called *safe-navigation-operator* (?).

```
*ngIf="!email?.valid"
```

This is similar to doing:

```
*ngIf="email && !email.valid"
```

More info: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator